# TRACE32, System.up command for PPC5646C does not work

Tags: lauterbach

could you please help me with an error, that I am getting after command SYStem.up of TRACE32 Lauterbach Debugger. It gives me back an error code: "emulation pod configuration error "

I would be grateful for any hints!

Thanks

Alexander

Answer (score 1):

This error can have three sources: 
 The CPU selection in the SYStem window does not match the CPU on the
target. Check if the selection matches the processor on the target. Try to
use auto detection (PPC..XX selection) if available.
 The CPU detection failed. Check the JTAG connection to the target.
 The CPU on the target is not supported by the used debugger software
release. In most cases there is additional information given in the AREA
window.

Check Lauterbach website for any software update for your CPU.